# Error in Updating dbModel of entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This blow code for my post edit action :

```
public ActionResult EditProduct(EditProductModel viewModel,HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (Session["AdminId"] != null && Session["AdminName"] != null)
        {
            repository = new Repository();
            var pro = repository.FindProductById(viewModel.Id);

            // Automappper configoration.
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cgf => cgf.CreateMap<EditProductModel, Product>());
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            pro = mapper.Map<Product>(viewModel);

            repository.UpdateProduct(pro);// Error
            repository.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("ShowProduct",new{id = AdminId});
        }
        return RedirectToAction("AdminLogin");
    }
```

The repository.UpdateProduct() Containing this code:

```
public void UpdateProduct(Product obj)
    {

        entities.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

But this top code throws this error :

> Attaching an entity of type 'MobileShop.Models.Product' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

How I can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this lines for updating and saving:

```
  using (var Context = new MobileDatabase_1_Entities())
  {
    Context.Entry(pro).State = EntityState.Modified;
    Context.SaveChanges();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `pro` object is already loaded from context, and it is tracked by EF. Changing it's state to modified in Update method is redundant, and hence giving this error.

So you can either skip the code in your `Update` method that changes the state,

OR comment out the following lines, because you are anyway building your entity from `viewModel`

```
repository = new Repository();
var pro = repository.FindProductById(viewModel.Id);
```

As a rule; if an object has been loaded from context, dont attach it
And if it has been created outside the context, set its state to modified.

A good read - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Comment: @komeilshahmoradi - You can comment out the above line. Next build your `pro` entity (you are already doing it), make sure it has got the same `Id` as in view model. Keep the `Update` method unchanged. This should work

Comment: @komeilshahmoradi - can you please share the error you are getting, and the new code?